# photoshop character panel clears when clicking somewhere else

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hello when I click some text, the character panel fills with info like this:

[image]

But when I click into another window it clears out like this:

[image]

Is there a setting where if I click into another window, it keeps the information in the panel?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "when I click some text". Are you trying to select some text? Is it an editable text layer?  Are you trying to type some text? What do you mean by "another window". Do you mean another document, or another artboard, or something else?n What version of Photoshop are you using?  Have you tried resetting the Preferences?

Comment: @BillyKerr Sorry i should of been more specific. When selecting text, I mean I am pressing 't' and clicking on an edible text layer. When clicking another window I mean clicking another window besides photoshop, such as a web browser. I am on version 19.1.4 and no I have not reset the preferences yet

Comment: You should have added those new details into your question.  What happens when you click back in Photohsop on the text tool?  Does that fix it?

Comment: unfortunately it does not, it remains empty

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Sorry about that.